# Sync not working after SqlSyncStoreMetadataCleanup

Tags: c#, sql-server, microsoft-sync-framework

I have perform a `SqlSyncStoreMetadataCleanup` in both server and client databases.(Both are MSSql Servers). Now when I start to sync ,some scopes are not synchronising (application keeps running)

How to overcome this situation?

**UPDATE :**
I got the following error after debugging.

> Cannot enumerate changes at the RelationalSyncProvider because the remote peer is outdated. See the OutdatedDbSyncException that was thrown for more details.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. Did you find the solution?

Comment: no I couldn't find a solution